# Media Services Job cannot encode an Append Blob but works fine using a Block Blob

Tags: azure, jobs, chunks, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Services and I need to encode an Append Blob using Job, the error I get from the Job is this:

> ```
> While trying to download the input files, the files were not accessible, please check the availability of the source.
> ```

**I must mention that the Append Blob is created by uploading a video file in chunks. Also, if I try to encode a Block Blob, it works perfectly.**

Is Azure Media Services restricting the Job to only work on Block Blob or is there another problem that makes the job fail?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I just found that media services assets only accept Block Blobs.
More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/assets-concept), this is the only article I found that talks about the type of blob stored in an asset...

> An Asset is mapped to a blob container in the Azure Storage account and the files in the Asset are stored as block blobs in that container.

Comment: Yes, We only support Block blobs.  But I would be curious what your scenario is? Are you trying to grow a live stream and encode it as it is growing? 
The live streaming service in AMS writes content in a series of MP4 chunks, and the archive file can be transcoded or passed to the analyzer presets.  
Are you doing something with a live stream, or are you just optimizing uploads?

Comment: Optimizing uploads for now